# Use "cmd /c" but hide the console window

Tags: cmd, windows-console

I have a shortcut running this command when clicked: `cmd /c "full path to my batch file"`. When I use it, it does what it is supposed to do, but in the process the ugly console window pops up. Is there any way to make this command start a hidden or at least minimized window?

Comment: It shouldn't show, but windows has a history of doing things differently, so really there isn't an easy way. You are better off creating a service if you really want it to run in the background.

Comment: in the shortcut there is a dropdown under the command where you can choose Normal Window or Minimized

Answer (score 23):

Use the command [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) with switch `/min` to start `cmd` in minimized window:

```
start /min cmd /c "full path to my batch file"
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It answers the question correctly ("... or minimized")

Comment: If use this way in the registry for a context menu item, the item stops work correctly

Comment: Or `/wait /min cmd /c "full path to my batch file"`.

Answer (score 18):

```
powershell "start <path of batch file> -Args \"<batch file args>\" -WindowStyle Hidden"
```

This can be placed in a separate batch file which, when called, will terminate immediately while your batch file executes in the background.

From ' Args ' to ' \" ' can be excluded if your batch file has no arguments.

' -v runAs' can be added before the end quote to run your batch file as an administrator.

Answer (score 8):

I found this solution :

Create a launch.vbs file and add

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Replace "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat" by your absolute or relative path file name.

Source : https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/

Source MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the shortcut icon and choose "Properties."

On the "Shortcut" tab, choose the "Run" type you desire from the dropdown menu.

The `START` command has a /B switch to start without creating a window. Use `START /?` to read all about it.

Answer (score 3):

Use **AutoHotKey** file. Download and install AutoHotKey first.

suppose you have an 1.bat

you'll create a C:\2.ahk, whose content is

```
Run C:\1.bat,,Hide
return
```

and you'll create a 3.lnk, and right click it, click property, then set the Target to

```
"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" C:\2.ahk
```

Then you'll get what you want.

This way, you can attach the 3.lnk to your taskbar or start menu, and also change its icon.

The start method can only be used in a bat, which can't be added to taskbar or changed icon.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a separate process (without a window), and not block parent window so it can continue your main work:

```
start /b cmd /c "full path to my batch file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a VBScript file as a shell to start it.

```vb
' Launcher.vbs
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

Dim WSH
Set WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSH.Run "cmd /c " & WScript.Arguments(0), 0, False
```

You may want to embed this as a Here Document in your batch file. See [heredoc for Windows batch?](/q/1015163/5958455)

Comment: Make sure that wscript.exe runs .vbs files instead of cscript.exe, else a console will briefly flash. You can configure this from the command prompt via `cscript //H:WScript`. Using wscript.exe should be the default.

Comment: In general you need quotes around the argument, e.g. `WSH.Run "cmd /c """ & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False`. Otherwise CMD will mess up the quoting when it strips the first and last quote in case the command starts with a quoted path for the executable and there's at least one more quoted argument in the command line.